# How to convert sink from 0.1 futures to 0.3 futures

Tags: rust

I am updating my codebase to futures 0.3 from futures 0.1. My function which used to work looks like this:

```
fn sink_task(
        message: String,
        sink: Box<
            Sink<
                SinkItem = datum::Message,
                SinkError = tungstenite::error::Error,
            >,
        >,
    )
```

I try to make it fit the new 0.3 futures Sink definition

```
pub trait Sink<Item> {
    type Error;
}
```

Like this:

```
fn sink_task(
        message: String,
        sink: Box<
            Sink<
                Item = datum::Message,
                Error = tungstenite::error::Error,
            >,
        >,
    )
```

But get an error saying wrong number of arguments, expected one. I assume that means to remove the Error argument, but then I still get an error, saying Error is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Item` argument is a generic parameter in 0.3, not an associated type. So the correct syntax is `Sink<datum::Message, Error = tungstenite::error::Error>`